# Increasing code coverage for a scheduled Batchable class

Tags: unit-test, batch, schedulebatch

Can any one help me out.In our org we have Test Class for Batch apex and Schedule class is combinedly written but code coverage is displaying 70%.How can i increase the code coverage.ANy help very much appreciated.

**Batch Apex**

```
global class UpdateAccountFields implements Database.Batchable<sObject>
{
    public string mode;
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        String query;
        if(mode == 'filter')
        {
            query = 'Select Id, Accountid,StageName,Closedate,LeadSource From Opportunity Where LastModifiedDate = TODAY OR LastModifiedDate = YESTERDAY';
        }
        else if(mode == 'all')
        {
            query = 'Select Id, Accountid,StageName,Closedate,LeadSource From Opportunity';
        }
        system.debug('mode##########'+mode);
        System.debug('QUERY:::' + query);
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }   

    global void execute(database.batchablecontext BC , list<Opportunity> sc)
    {
        system.debug('sc####################'+sc);
        Set<Id> relatedAccountIds = new Set<Id>();
        if(sc.size() >0)
        {
            for(Opportunity opp : sc)
            {
                relatedAccountIds.add(opp.Accountid);                       
            }
        }
        system.debug('relatedAccountIds::::::::::::;'+relatedAccountIds);
        List<ID> relatedAccountList = new List<ID>(relatedAccountIds);

        Map<ID, Account> relatedAccounts = new Map<ID, Account>(
        [SELECT Id, Customer_Status__c,Tier_Level__c ,Current_Active_ARR_Customer__c,Total_ARR_As_of_Today__c,Business_Categories__c ,Business_Segment__c , Number_of_won_opps__c, Number_of_open_opportunities__c, 
        Number_of_Open_Non_Renewal_Opportunities__c,Traning_sold__c,Subscriptions_sold__c,Services_sold__c,Last_Opportunity_Close_Date__c,ARR_Customer__c,Current_ARR_Customer__c,Last_Renewal_Close_Date__c, Last_NonRenewal_Opportunity_Won_Date__c,Customer_List__c,
        Number_of_Open_Renewal_Opportunities__c, Do_Not_Override_Tier_Level__c
        from Account where Id in :relatedAccountList]);

        Set<ID> accountsToUpdate = new Set<ID>(); // List of account IDs to update

        Map<id,List<Opportunity>> OpptyMap  = new Map<id,List<Opportunity>>(); 
        Map<id,List<OpportunityLineitem>> OpptyolilistMap  = new Map<id,List<OpportunityLineitem>>(); 
        Map<id,List<Contract>> AccountContractlistMap  = new Map<id,List<Contract>>(); 

        List<Opportunity> oList = new List<Opportunity>();

        ///get all opportunities for that Account and create opp Map///
        oList = [Select Id, Accountid,StageName,Closedate,LeadSource From Opportunity Where AccountId In : relatedAccountList AND StageName = 'Closed Won' order By CloseDate DESC ];
        List<Opportunity> tmplist;

        for(Opportunity o : oList)
        {       
            if(!OpptyMap.containskey(o.AccountId))
            {
                tmpList = new List<Opportunity>();
                tmpList.add(o);
                OpptyMap.put(o.AccountId,tmpList);
            }   
            else
            {
                tmpList = OpptyMap.get(o.AccountId);
                tmpList.add(o);         
            }
        }

        ///Create Map///
        List<OpportunityLineitem> oliList = new List<OpportunityLineitem>();

        oliList = [Select OpportunityId,TotalPrice,Total_Price_Total_Transfer_Price__c,Type_Of_Product__c,Product_Bucket__c,Services__c,ARR_Impacts__c,Subscription__c,Total_Transfer_price__c From OpportunityLineitem Where OpportunityId in : oList];

        List<OpportunityLineItem>templist;

        if(oliList.size() > 0)
        {
            for(OpportunityLineItem oli : oliList)
            {       
                if(!OpptyolilistMap.containskey(oli.Opportunityid))
                {
                    tempList = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
                    tempList.add(oli);
                    OpptyolilistMap.put(oli.Opportunityid,tempList);
                }   
                else
                {
                    tempList = OpptyolilistMap.get(oli.Opportunityid);
                    tempList.add(oli);
                    OpptyolilistMap.put(oli.Opportunityid,tempList);
                }
            }
        }   

        List<Contract> conList = new List<Contract>();
        //conList = [Select Opportunity_Name__c,EndDate,StartDate,Status,Annual_Recurring_Revenue__c,No_Future_ARR_Consideration__c From Contract Where Opportunity_Name__c in : oList];

        conList = [Select AccountId, Opportunity_Name__c,EndDate,StartDate,Status,Annual_Recurring_Revenue__c,No_ARR_Consideration__c, No_Future_ARR_Consideration__c From Contract Where AccountId in : relatedAccountList];

        List<Contract>templist1;

        if(conList.size() > 0)
        {
            for(Contract con : conList)
            {       
                //if(!AccountContractlistMap.containskey(con.Opportunity_Name__c))
                if(!AccountContractlistMap.containskey(con.AccountId))
                {
                    tempList1 = new List<Contract>();
                    tempList1.add(con);
                    //AccountContractlistMap.put(con.Opportunity_Name__c,tempList1);
                    AccountContractlistMap.put(con.AccountId,tempList1);
                }   
                else
                {
                    //tempList1 = AccountContractlistMap.get(con.Opportunity_Name__c);
                    tempList1 = AccountContractlistMap.get(con.AccountId);
                    tempList1.add(con);
                    //AccountContractlistMap.put(con.Opportunity_Name__c,tempList1);
                    AccountContractlistMap.put(con.AccountId,tempList1);
                }
            }
        }   

        for(string key : relatedAccounts.keySet())
        {
            Account act = relatedAccounts.get(key);
            Decimal Amt = 0.00;
            Decimal Amt1= 0.00;
            Decimal Amt2 = 0.00;
            Decimal Amt3 = 0.00;
            if(!OpptyMap.containskey(act.id))
            {
                act.Traning_sold__c = 0.00;
                act.Subscriptions_sold__c = 0.00;
                act.Services_sold__c = 0.00;
                system.debug('act.Subscriptions_sold__c^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^'+act.Subscriptions_sold__c);
            }
            else if(OpptyMap.containskey(act.id))
            {
                for(Opportunity op: OpptyMap.get(act.Id))
                {

                      if(op.StageName == 'Closed Won')
                      {
                        //Get the latest date from Opportunity list//
                        if((act.Last_Opportunity_Close_Date__c != null && act.Last_Opportunity_Close_Date__c < op.CloseDate) || act.Last_Opportunity_Close_Date__c == null)
                        {
                            act.Last_Opportunity_Close_Date__c = op.CloseDate;
                            accountsToUpdate.add(act.id);                   
                        }
                        if(op.LeadSource == 'Subscription Renewal' && ((act.Last_Renewal_Close_Date__c != null && act.Last_Renewal_Close_Date__c < op.CloseDate) || act.Last_Renewal_Close_Date__c == null))
                        {
                            act.Last_Renewal_Close_Date__c = op.CloseDate;                  
                            accountsToUpdate.add(act.id);
                        }

                        if(OpptyolilistMap.containskey(Op.id))
                        {
                            for(OpportunityLineItem oli : OpptyolilistMap.get(Op.id))
                            {
                                if(oli.Product_Bucket__c != null  && oli.Product_Bucket__c.contains('Training'))
                                {
                                    Amt += oli.Total_Price_Total_Transfer_Price__c;                         
                                    accountsToUpdate.add(act.id);
                                }
                                if(oli.Product_Bucket__c != null  && (oli.Product_Bucket__c.contains('Subscription') || (oli.Product_Bucket__c.contains('Embedded Sales') && oli.ARR_Impacts__c == 'Yes')))
                                {
                                    Amt1 += oli.Total_Price_Total_Transfer_Price__c;                            
                                    accountsToUpdate.add(act.id);
                                }
                                if(oli.Product_Bucket__c != null  && (oli.Product_Bucket__c == 'Services' || (oli.Product_Bucket__c.contains('Embedded Sales') && oli.ARR_Impacts__c == 'No')))
                                {
                                    Amt2 += oli.Total_Price_Total_Transfer_Price__c;                          
                                    accountsToUpdate.add(act.id);
                                }
                                if(oli.ARR_Impacts__c == 'Yes')
                                {
                                    act.ARR_Customer__c = true;
                                    accountsToUpdate.add(act.id);
                                }
                            }
                            act.Traning_sold__c = Amt;
                            act.Subscriptions_sold__c = Amt1;
                            act.Services_sold__c = Amt2;
                            accountsToUpdate.add(act.id); 
                            system.debug('act.Traning_sold__c!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!'+act.Traning_sold__c);
                        }
                    }           
                }
            }

            ///////Updating Account on basis of Contracts////////////////
            if(AccountContractlistMap.containskey(act.id))
            {
                for(Contract c : AccountContractlistMap.get(act.id))
                {
                    //system.debug('cond2::' + (c.EndDate >= system.Today()) + '::' +  (c.StartDate <= system.Today()) + '::' +  (c.No_Future_ARR_Consideration__c == false || (c.No_Future_ARR_Consideration__c == true &&  c.StartDate >= system.Today())) + '::' +  (c.Annual_Recurring_Revenue__c != 0) + '::' +  (act.Customer_List__c == true) +'::' +  (c.No_ARR_Consideration__c != true));

                    //system.debug('cond 1::' + (c.EndDate >= system.Today() && c.StartDate <= system.Today() && (c.No_Future_ARR_Consideration__c == false || (c.No_Future_ARR_Consideration__c == true &&  c.StartDate >= system.Today())) && c.Annual_Recurring_Revenue__c != 0 && act.Customer_List__c == true && c.No_ARR_Consideration__c != true));
                    if(c.EndDate >= system.Today() && c.StartDate <= system.Today() && (c.No_Future_ARR_Consideration__c == false || (c.No_Future_ARR_Consideration__c == true &&  c.StartDate <= system.Today())) && c.Annual_Recurring_Revenue__c != 0 && act.Customer_List__c == true && c.No_ARR_Consideration__c != true)
                    {
                        Amt3 += c.Annual_Recurring_Revenue__c;
                        accountsToUpdate.add(act.id); 
                        system.debug('Amt3!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!'+Amt3);
                    }
                }
                act.Total_ARR_As_of_Today__c = Amt3;
                if(act.Total_ARR_As_of_Today__c != 0)
                {
                    act.Current_Active_ARR_Customer__c = true;                          
                }
                else
                {
                    act.Current_Active_ARR_Customer__c = false;                         
                }
                accountsToUpdate.add(act.id); 
            }
            if(act.Tier_Level__c != 'No Touch' && !act.Do_Not_Override_Tier_Level__c)
            {
                if((act.Business_Segment__c == 'F500/G2000'|| act.Total_ARR_As_of_Today__c >= 100000) && act.Current_Active_ARR_Customer__c == true)
                {
                    act.Tier_Level__c = 'Tier 1';                    
                }
                else if((act.Business_Categories__c == 'High-Value' || (act.Business_Categories__c == 'High-Volume' && act.Total_ARR_As_of_Today__c >= 50000 &&  act.Total_ARR_As_of_Today__c < 99000)) && act.Tier_Level__c != 'Tier 1' && act.Current_Active_ARR_Customer__c == true)
                {
                    act.Tier_Level__c = 'Tier 2';                    
                }
                else if(act.Business_Categories__c == 'High-Volume' && (act.Tier_Level__c != 'Tier 2' || act.Tier_Level__c != 'Tier 1') && act.Current_Active_ARR_Customer__c == true)
                {
                    act.Tier_Level__c = 'Tier 3';                
                }
                else
                {
                   act.Tier_Level__c = '';                
                }
            }
            accountsToUpdate.add(act.id);
        }
        List<Account> accountListToUpdate = new List<Account>();
        for(ID theid: accountsToUpdate) 
            accountListToUpdate.add(relatedAccounts.get(theid));
        update accountListToUpdate;
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext info)
    {     

    } 
}
```

**Schedule CLass**

```
global class scheduleUpdateAccountFields implements Schedulable 
{   
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) 
    {
        UpdateAccountFields batch = new UpdateAccountFields();
        batch.mode = 'filter';
        Database.executeBatch(batch);
    }   
}
```

Test CLass:

```
@isTest
private class TestUpdateAccountFields
{
   public static String CRON_EXP = '0 0 0 15 3 ? 2022';
   static testMethod void unitTest()
   {
        //Create Account
        Account acc =  new Account();       
        acc.Name = 'Compro';          
        acc.BillingStreet = '4 LSC';
        acc.BillingCity = 'New Delhi';
        acc.BillingState = 'Delhi';
        acc.BillingPostalCode = '110049';
        acc.BillingCountry = 'India';
        acc.Phone = '100';
        acc.Industry = 'Banking';         
        acc.Type = 'Paid';
        acc.Customer_Type__c = 'Customer';
        acc.Customer_List__c = true;    
        acc.Traning_sold__c = 0.00;
        acc.Subscriptions_sold__c = 0.00;
        acc.Services_sold__c = 0.00;
        acc.Last_Opportunity_Close_Date__c = null; 
        acc.ARR_Customer__c = false;
        acc.Current_ARR_Customer__c = false;
        acc.Last_Renewal_Close_Date__c = null;
        //acc.Number_of_won_opps__c == null;
        insert acc;     

        //Create Contact
        Contact con =  new Contact();
        con.LeadSource = 'Web';                 
        con.FirstName = 'ABC';
        con.LastName = 'XYZ';
        con.MailingStreet = '4 LSC';
        con.MailingCity = 'New Delhi';
        con.MailingState = 'Delhi';
        con.MailingPostalCode = '110049';
        con.MailingCountry = 'India';
        con.Phone = '100';             
        con.AccountId = acc.Id ;
        con.Email = 'xyz@xyz.com';
        con.ContactType__c = 1;
        insert con;     


        //Create Opportunity
        Opportunity oppty =  new Opportunity();
        oppty.Ecommerce_Transaction_ID__c = 999;
        oppty.LeadSource = 'Subscription Renewal';
        oppty.Name = 'Test Oppty';
        oppty.CloseDate = System.Today()+100;
        oppty.StageName = 'Closed Won';                     
        oppty.Compelling_Event__c = 'N/A';
        oppty.NextStep = 'N/A';
        oppty.Decision_Maker__c  = 'N/A';
        oppty.Comments__c = 'N/A';
        oppty.Committed__c = true;
        oppty.Billing_Contact__c = con.Id;
        oppty.Payment_Type__c = 'Credit Card';
        oppty.Partner__c = 'None';
        oppty.AccountId = acc.Id;
        oppty.Update_Complete__c = true;                    
        insert oppty;

        //Add oppty contact role
        string stdpdId = '01s500000001e6k';
        List<OpportunityContactRole> ocrList = new List<OpportunityContactRole>();          
        OpportunityContactRole opptyConRole = new OpportunityContactRole();           
        opptyConRole.ContactId = con.Id;
        opptyConRole.OpportunityId = oppty.Id;   
        opptyConRole.IsPrimary = true;
        opptyConRole.Role = 'Subscription Administrator';  
        insert opptyConRole;

        //Product type support
        Product2 prd1 = new Product2();
        prd1.Name = 'Protection Suite for Linux Multi-site Upgrade - 5 Year Support';
        prd1.IsActive = true;
        prd1.Family = 'PostgreSQL';
        prd1.Description = 'Protection Suite for Linux Multi-site Upgrade - 5 Year Support';
        prd1.ProductCode = 'SE-LB-MSCU-S5';
        prd1.ARR_Impact1__c = 'Yes';
        prd1.Notes__c = 'Steeleye Reseller Agreement';
        prd1.Payment_Terms__c = 'test';
        prd1.Product_Bucket__c = 'Subscription - Multi-year';
        prd1.Product_Categories__c = 'Subscription - Multi-year';
        prd1.Product_Segmentation__c = 'External Products';
        prd1.Product_Name1__c = 'Product - Support';
        prd1.Term__c = '5';
        prd1.Unit_of_Measure__c = 'Server';
        insert prd1;

        PricebookEntry pbe1 = new PricebookEntry();
        pbe1.Product2ID=prd1.id;
        pbe1.Pricebook2ID=stdpdId;
        pbe1.UnitPrice=50; 
        pbe1.isActive=true;
        insert pbe1;

        OpportunityLineItem oli =  new OpportunityLineItem();           
        oli.OpportunityId = oppty.Id;            
        oli.UnitPrice = 100;
        oli.Quantity = 1;
        oli.PricebookEntryId = pbe1.Id;
        oli.Start_Date__c = System.today();
        oli.End_Date__c =  System.today() + 100;
        oli.Term__c = 12;
        //oli.TotalPrice = 12;
        OLI.Transfer_Price__c = 12;
        oli.Quantity = 2;
        insert oli;

       Test.startTest();
       String jobId = System.schedule('Test Schedule', CRON_EXP, new scheduleUpdateAccountFields());
       Test.stopTest();
   }
}
```

Comment: A test class that is not. It's just an execution script. You have no idea if anything is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the essence of your problem:

1. The underlying batch class has multiple if - else statements indicating that you will need multiple test objects to pass into the batch in order to cover the various paths
2. Yet your test class only inserts one Account, one Oppo, one OCR, one OLI so it is no wonder some of the if - true or if - false paths aren't being traversed.

You should think less about code coverage and more about setting up tests to verify via asserts that the batchable class does what it is supposed to do.  This is going to require setting up various multi-sobject datasets using Test Factories, `Test.loadData()`, or your own concoction. Using good naming conventions for your test data can aid in noting for the future what each test object represents in a business sense.

If you take the above approach, you'll find that you'll get:

- Much higher confidence that your business logic is correct
- Inspiration / realization that there are legitimate data scenarios that your code doesn't (yet) handle
- 90+% code coverage

And, then, you can examine the uncovered lines and enhance your test set since you've built out a nice infrastructure for business use case variations.

The regression set you end up with will vastly increase confidence on future deployments that you didn't break anything with some enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to watch out for:

```
Test.startTest();
   String jobId = System.schedule('Test Schedule', CRON_EXP, new scheduleUpdateAccountFields());
Test.stopTest();
```

The `Test.stopTest()` here will force the scheduleUpdateAccountFields.execute() method to run but it will **not** force the inner Apex Batch to run. The Apex Batch will get added to the queue but not necessarily run.

You need at least one more test method to test the Apex Batch itself.

Something like this:

```
// set up test data etc

Test.startTest();
    UpdateAccountFields batch = new UpdateAccountFields();
    batch.mode = 'filter';
    Database.executeBatch(batch);
Test.stopTest();
```

The `Test.stopTest()` here will force the Apex Batch to run in its entirety.